# Filtering out non-zero values unless the value is the only one within its group (SQL or R)

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a data set of record numbers, with multiple values in a column for each record. I would like to produce a table where within each group it returns the minimum non-negative, non-NA value. *But* if that negative number or NA corresponds to the only row for that record, then I would like it to return NA.

```
data <- data.frame(record = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4), value = c(-1, 2, 40, -10, 3, 4, NA))

| record | value |
------------------
|   1    |  -1   |
|   1    |   2   |
|   1    |   40  |
|   2    |  -10  |
|   3    |   3   |
|   3    |   4   |
|   4    |   NA  |
------------------
```

I would like to get

```
| record |  out  |
------------------
|   1    |   2   |
|   2    |  NA   |
|   3    |   3   |
|   4    |  NA   |
------------------
```

In R I have tried:

```
filter(data, value >= 0 | is.na(value))
data %>% group_by(record) %>% summarize(out = min(value))
```

In MySQL I have tried

```
select min(value) as out
from data
where (value >= 0 or value is null))
```

However, both of these solutions drop record #2 from the table.

How do I include a clause that detects the number of rows per record and doesn't eliminate single records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `replace` those 'value' less than 0 to `NA`, grouped by 'record', `slice` the rows where we get the `min` of 'value' or if all are `NA`, get the first row

```
data %>%
   mutate(value = replace(value, value < 0, NA)) %>% 
   group_by(record) %>% 
   slice(if(all(is.na(value))) 1 else which.min(value))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   record [4]
#  record value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
#1      1     2
#2      2    NA
#3      3     3
#4      4    NA
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still appears to be eliminating record 2.

Comment: Oops, my previous comment was before the edit, now it's working

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, .(out = if(any(pos <- value >= 0, na.rm = T)) 
                  min(value[pos]) 
                else NA_real_)
     , by = record]

#    record out
# 1:      1   2
# 2:      2  NA
# 3:      3   3
# 4:      4  NA
```

Or if you don't like doing assignment in a function argument

```
data[, {pos <- value >= 0
        .(out = if(any(pos, na.rm = T)) min(value[pos]) else NA_real_)}
     , by = record]
```

Here's an option with sqldf. Not sure if there's a more efficient SQL option. edit: A simpler SQL option is given in the comments

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('
select    a.record
          , b.out
from      data a
          left join (
            select    record
                      , min(value) as out
            from      data
            where     value >= 0
            group by  record
          ) b
            on a.record = b.record
group by  a.record
')
#   record out
# 1      1   2
# 2      2  NA
# 3      3   3
# 4      4  NA
```

Comment: This would also work: `sqldf("select record, min(case when value >- 0 then value else Null end) as out from data group by record")` using the default SQLite backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from elegant, but if none of the above solutions work for you, here's something that will do exactly what you're looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(record = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4), value = c(-1, 2, 40, -10, 3, 4, NA))
a<-rownames(data[data$value<0|is.na(data$value),])
data$value[as.integer(a)]<-NA

data<-data %>% group_by(record) %>% summarize(out = min(value,na.rm = TRUE))
data$out[data$out=="Inf"]<-NA
```